# How to predict TWO categorical variables using ML classificator?

Tags: python, prediction, categorical-data, multilabel-classification

I need to create a model that would predict two categorical variables 'Your main stack' and 'Position', using the rest independent variables as predictors.

It is easy to handle only one predictor, but now I am dealing with 2 variables.

Any help will be appreciated.[image]

Comment: Depends on what algorithm/package you're using. Not sure about CatBoost but XGBoost allows multi-output predictions out-of-the-box.

Comment: Also check out algorithms with multi-class and multi-output classification on sklearn: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html